# Diagnal / Perspective guide lines in photshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Ive got an image of a dial that i need to rotate i need to line this up with some other items that are not on a horizontal line.

What id like to do is be able to draw a guide line for reference but i can only seem to be able to draw vertical and horizontal guide lines, any idea how i can draw diagonal guide lines ?

Comment: http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/vanishing-point.html

Comment: Also just discovered perspective warp tool in PSCC - http://tv.adobe.com/watch/creative-cloud-for-photographers/perspective-warp-in-photoshop-cc-142/ - can be helpful when trying to manipulate the perspective of elements